# Div:hover and overwrite another class style assigned to the same div

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors, hover

I just encountered the issue, that I cant find out how to overwrite another class' style i.e. Background Color on hovering another class of same div. My example:

```
<div class="shapeClass bgTransparentGrey"></div>
<div class="shapeClass bgTransparentGrey"></div>
<div class="shapeClass bgTransparentGrey"></div>
```

the class **shapeClass** defines the shape, the class **bgTransparentGrey** defines the bg color. On **shapeClass:hover** i want to change styles of the **bgTransparentGrey** class, but only to the hovered element.

Best
Tassilo

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Classes don't have values. Are you asking how to remove the div from the classToBeEditedOnHover and add it to a different one? You need JavaScript to do that.

Comment: maybe the wrong word. Im trying to change i.e. a background color of "classToBeEditedOnHover" when hovering "classToDetectHover" with pure css. Both classes are attached to the same element

Comment: This still makes no sense. You are hovering over an element, not a class.

Comment: hm?
im mean something like .classToDetectHover:hover .classToBeEditedOnHover{

Comment: Are you maybe actually trying to say that you want _all_ elements that have the class `classToBeEditedOnHover` throughout the whole document to change their background color, when this specific div element with the class `classToDetectHover` gets hovered? That is not generally possible using CSS (it would be in limited ways for elements in the right position in the DOM structure), you’re gonna need JS for that.

Comment: _“im mean something like `.classToDetectHover:hover .classToBeEditedOnHover{`”_ - that would affect all _descendant_ elements with the class `classToBeEditedOnHover` that are _inside_ the element with the class `classToDetectHover`.

Comment: yes, but I dont want to affect a child element with the class classToBeEditedOnHover. I want to affect the same level class so sth like **level1ClassA:hover level1.classB**. i dont want to affect all elements with this class.
so in other words im looking for a way to stay on same level in css instead of going on child level.
To give a real example:
**<div class="boxElement bgTransparentGrey"></div>**
the class boxElement defines the shape, the class bgTransparentGrey defines the bg color. There are multiple elements with the bg class. On box hover i want to affect the bgTransparent class

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the attributes of a class on the fly with Javascript. You would need to write an additional class that you add that overwrites the others styling.

```js
$('.container-styles').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('overwrite-styles');
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('overwrite-styles');  
})
```

```css
.container-styles {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.overwrite-styles {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-styles"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Blake, I think u misunderstood me. I added some more info to my initial question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector which will only affect elements which have BOTH classes:

```
.boxElement.bgTransparentGrey { ... }
```

If you place that somewhere BELOW/AFTER the rules for the single classes in your stylesheet, settings in it will overwrite the previous settings.

(note: there is no space between the classes, therefore it only applies when both classes are assigned to the same element)